# Flex 3 PopUpManager does not correctly enable Accessibility features

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, accessibility, flexbuilder

I have an application written with Flex 3.6 and when I create a modal popup dialog, the buttons and text on that popup do not work correctly with the Accessibility properties that I have defined.  The app is compiled with the accessibility flag.

I build a simple app to test demonstrate the problem.

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
                layout="vertical">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.containers.TitleWindow;
            import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

            private var titleWindow:TitleWindow;

            private function popUp():void {
                titleWindow = PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, CustomTitleWindow, true) as TitleWindow;
                PopUpManager.centerPopUp(titleWindow);
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:Button label="Launch TitleWindow" click="popUp()" />

</mx:Application>
```

and the CustomTitleWindow.mxml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:TitleWindow xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
                title="popup titlewindow"
                layout="vertical"
                width="200"
                height="200"
                showCloseButton="true"
                close="titleWindow_close(event)">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.CloseEvent;
            import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

            private function titleWindow_close(evt:CloseEvent):void {
                PopUpManager.removePopUp(this)
            }

            private function titleWindow_continue():void {
                PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:Text text="How now brown cow."
        width="100%" />

    <mx:Button label="Continue"
        click="titleWindow_continue()" />

</mx:TitleWindow>
```

Now when I build the application, and run the Inspect tool to view the MSAA accessibility info, the "Continue" button on the titlewindow does not get highlighted.  This means that a screen reader or tool like Dragon NaturallySpeaking will not work when you say "Click Continue" to it.

I built the swf as an executable swf with the Flash 9.0r124 runtime (not debug) with Northcode's SWF studio, but the same thing is seen with later flash runtimes (10 and 11)

Below is a view of the inspect tool looking at my app with the titlewindow open, and the mouse cursor over the Continue button

[image: screenshot of test flex app and inspect tool]

what I should be seeing is the Continue button highlighted in yellow

Any idea how to get the accessibility features to work correctly with modal popup windows created using Flex's PopupManager?

It will not help me by going to Flex 4.x, but I wrote a quick test application and it appears that in Flex 4.5.1 at least the problem is fixed, see screenshot below.  We are currently stuck with an application using the Flex 3.6 runtime, and cant make the upgrade to Flex 4.x yet

[image: screenshot of flex 4.5.1]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should give the rollover effect to the Continue button or change the rollover style. that is the easiest way for that and one more way for that is you can create a custom button for that but it is a very complex way. so i prefer the first way is the best one.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the problem here.  The yellow highlight box is drawn by the Microsoft Inspect tool, which basically follows the mouse cursor and shows you what MSAA properties of UI elements on the screen.  Read more on it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521(v=vs.85).aspx  The problem is that the Flex SDK doesnt allow the MSAA properties to be seen by any third party tools when you create a modal dialog with the PopupManager in Flex.  I use the Inspect tool to allow me to visually see what Dragon NaturallySpeaking would allow the user to speak

Comment: i have mis understood the problem and given the answer. So sorry for that.